# Help to compute $\mathrm{Tor}_{n}^{\mathbb{Z}_{4}}(\mathbb{Z}_{2},\mathbb{Z}_{2})$?

Tags: homological-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$-module. How to compute $\mathrm{Tor}_{n}^{\mathbb{Z}_{4}}(\mathbb{Z}_{2},\mathbb{Z}_{2})$?

Comment: Indeed, this is one situation where "just apply the definition" works...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a free (or projective) resolution of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. One is
$$\dots\to\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_4$$
where every arrow is multiplication by $2$. Now you tensor this complex (over $\mathbb{Z}_4$) with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and you get
$$\dots\to\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2$$
where the arrows are now zero. Your Tor's are the cohomology of this complex. As a result, they are $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for every $n$.

Comment: You need the rightmost memeber of your free resolution to be $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @user8268: thanks, I just didn't know where to start, thanks again.

Comment: @Thomas: (it may depend on conventions, but) there is no $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the resolution; in principle it continues to the right, with zeroes. The resolution should be a non-positively graded complex (of free $\mathbb{Z}_4$-modules) with cohomology equal to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (only in deg. $0$ - for other degrees the cohomology should vanish). (but as I said, it might depend on conventions, so I'm just explaining what I meant)

Comment: Ah, I suppose that makes sense, but that requires that you define a project resolution in terms of cohomology, when you can instead define it "independent" of cohomology using just exact sequences.

Comment: Hi my friend.Could you describe it more?I couldn't understand  your answer.